# I am not able to filter my data with id , there is getting error entry.id is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const searchRecord = (value) => {
  let filtered = labListDetailsData.filter((entry) =>
    entry.patient.name.toLowerCase().includes(value)
  );
  let filteredBooking = labListDetailsData.filter((entry) =>
    entry.id.includes(value)
  );
  setLabListData(filtered || filteredBooking);
};
```

Comment: You should provide more information. Can you post the code where you initialize and update your `labListDetailsData` state?

Comment: if example data can be provided that would be easy to provide an answer, by the error it feels like id is not available in entry object.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.